# AndroidThings not working on Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: pi-3, android-things

Im trying to get any version of android running on my Raspberry Pie 3 B. Ive followed the [instructions here](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) and used these build settings

- OEM partition size: 512MB
- Using google play services
- empty bundle
- OS build: OIR1.170720.017

Im able to successfully flash the image onto a 64gb micro sd (with etcher) card but when I insert it into the Pi and power it on I see a rainbow screen flash a couple times and then it goes completely black. I have tried all OS builds and none of them work.

Another weird thing is once the flash of the sd card is complete my Mac is unable to read it and presents a pop up asking to initialize it. This is strange to me because when I have the stock raspberry by OS flashed on the sd card my Mac is able to display the filesystem.

Comment: My understanding is that Android on Raspberry Pi is not quite ready yet. I am not sure how much the work has advanced since this article about a year ago, https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/android-raspberry-pi/ on the other hand this more recent article talks about something called Android Things, https://www.hackster.io/Salmanfarisvp/getting-started-in-android-things-with-raspberry-pi-6a980e however it also seems to be lacking a few bits.

Comment: I tried the first link and the build works, however there is no google play store and downloading the apps from the online store does not install and run. Android things build is what this question is talking about not working. Have you experienced something different recently?

Comment: I was curious about Android on the Pi so did some investigation over the past month but after seeing the state of development decide it wasn't worth any further look right now. I am using both Raspbian and Windows 10 IoT but concentrating on Windows 10 IoT and Universal Windows Program (UWP) development at the moment. UWP is attractive as I have the ability to write programs that can run on either a PC or a Pi by just changing the build target and recompiling.

Comment: My impression is that apps in the Google Store would not run on a Pi due to the hardware architecture of the Pi as compared to Android phones. My understanding of Android Things is that it is a cut down version of Android similar to how Windows 10 IoT is a cut down version of Windows 10. Both Android Things and Windows 10 IoT are designed to support the hardware architecture of devices like the Pi or the Minnow rather than provide a full featured operating system and utilities.